# Xcode 8: how to turn off autosave

Tags: xcode8

Is it possible to turn off the autosave of edits in Xcode 8?

I've seen a post to run `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ApplePersistence -bool no` from a Terminal, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following Terminal command did the trick:

```
defaults write $(osascript -e 'id of application "Xcode"') ApplePersistence -bool False
```